# Calling methods from a FactoryGirl model in a dependent attribute

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I have a model similar to the following:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :attribute_a  # Really an ActiveRecord attribute
  attr_accessor :attribute_b  # Also an ActiveRecord attribute

  def determine_attribute_b
    self.attribute_b = some_biz_logic(attribute_a)
  end
end
```

In FactoryGirl 1.3, I had a factory that looked like this:

```
Factory.define :foo do |foo|
  foo.attribute_a = "some random value"
  foo.attribute_b { |f| f.determine_attribute_b }
end
```

This worked just fine. `attribute_b` was an attribute dependent on the code block, which would be passed a real instance of `Foo` into the variable `f`, complete with a properly set `attribute_a` to work off of.

I just upgraded to FactoryGirl 2.3.2, and this technique no longer works. The `f` variable from the equivalent code to above is no longer an instance of `Foo`, but instead a `FactoryGirl::Proxy::Create`. This class appears to be able to read the attributes previously set (such that the [Dependent Attributes example in the docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/2.3.2/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Dependent_Attributes) still works). However, it can't call actual methods from the built class.

Is there a way I can use the technique from the old version of FactoryGirl? I want to be able to define an attribute and set its value using the result of an instance method of the built class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the callbacks `after_create` and `after_build` like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    attribute_a "some random value"
    after_build do |obj|
      obj.attribute_b = obj.determine_attribute_b
    end
  end
end
```

Keep in mind this new `FactoryGirl` syntax.

Comment: By the way - may be you should consider calling determine_attribute_b  on before_create callback in you model. It seems reasonable as soon as you setting attribute_b in factory for your tests.

Comment: not a bad idea, but in my real-life code, I can't do that. There's cases when I want to set it independently in the controller code.

Comment: current syntax is `after(:build) do`